# Is Sera's Brother Shukichi Haneda?

Tags: detective-conan

I've just read the newest Detective Conan comic online. There's a case when Yumi calls Shukichi and Sera call her brother at the same time. When Yumi talks to Shukichi, Shukichi holds their conversation because someone else is calling at the same time. Sera calls her brother but Sera's Brother also stops their conversation because he is in an important call with someone. So, does that mean Sera's Brother is Shukichi Haneda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time unless and until canon says otherwise, it is reasonable to assume that Sera's brother is Shikichi Haneda.  However, Gosho Aoyama certainly knows how to mislead his readers, so it's definitely not a sure thing as far as I'm concerned.  See also [Shukichi Haneda](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Shukichi_Haneda#Yumi.27s_Love_Story_.28Manga:_847-849.3B_Anime:_731-732.29)

Comment: That doesn't exactly answer the question. Is he, or is he not?

Comment: @ Nolonar That's the point: there is no way to tell for sure. I've re-read the specific chapter (aka file), and given the way Sera and Yumi describe their respective brother and ex-boyfriend, it's reasonable in my opinion to conclude that those two people are one and the same.  As I also wrote, the mangaka of that series likes to trick his readers, and until the boyfriend-being-the-brother is officially and irrefutably revealed this is all we have to go on.

Comment: @Tive: I fully agree with you, the author points the evidence to that direction, but in this work, he as fooled the readers many times doing things like this.

Still, please, edit your aswer so it clearly states at the beggining that "It is still now known, as it was not oficcially confirmed nor denied".

Comment: @Sigfried666: done

Comment: @Tive yeah, I also agree with you, the way why I'm think Shukichi is Sera's brother also because there's a time Subaru Okiya/Shuichi Akai seems interesting when he read the news about Shukichi Haneda got his Meijin title in shogi.